# (there) came into view

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice

Should there be a *there* in the following? Why or why not?

> Half an hour later (there) came into view the familiar sight of a
> glass door and a neon sign.

Note: I guess there should be a comma after *later* if *there* is required.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to use _there_ to introduce  the sudden appearance of something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using **there** in this sentence. It sounds more natural than leaving it out.

In *principle,* an English sentence may have this structure:

> [adverb] + [verb] + [subject] + [whatever]

We see this in "The Charge of the Light Brigade," by Tennyson (published in 1854):

> Into the valley of Death
> Rode the six hundred.

Your sentence is similar. In place of **Into the valley of Death,** yours has **Half an hour later**—conceptually, not a big difference:

> Half an hour later
> came . . . the familiar sight . . .

But as you might guess from my example, this structure is typically confined to poetry. It is a remnant of Old English, where a system of cases permitted a more flexible word order.

Your version with **there** (and a comma) is more natural in today's prose:

> Version A: Half an hour later, there came into view the familiar sight of a glass door and a neon sign.

The structure is easily understood by native speakers, in part because it is very familiar. Countless fairy tales read to children begin like this:

> Once upon a time, there was a greedy king . . .
> Once upon a time, there was a little duck . . .
> Once upon a time, there lived a little princess . . .

However, the structure is still less common than the subject-verb structure that we use in most of our sentences. This next version is more conventional:

> Version B: Half an hour later, the familiar sight of a glass door and a neon sign came into view.

Your comment below confirms that you have already considered this version and cast it aside. I will briefly explain the principle. Your version uses the *stress position* of the sentence (i.e., the end) to emphasize **a glass door and a neon sign.**  You would lose this advantage if you ended with the words **came into view.** It's a small difference, to be sure, but it's the kind of difference that experienced writers make wherever they can. The cumulative effect is more coherent prose.

To be clear: If I have described the effect that your intuition was pushing you toward, then Version A (your version) might be the best. But if that seems wrong somehow, you might be better off with Version B (the conventional version).

Every language provides tools for managing emphasis. Using **there** to postpone the subject of a clause is a tool that English provides.

For more on this, see
Joseph M. Williams and Joseph Bizup, *Style*, "Emphasis"
Martha Kolln and Loretta Gray, *Rhetorical Grammar,* "Sentence Rhythm,"
Steven Pinker, *The Sense of Style*, "Save the heaviest for last."

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, you're right. I was following Stephen Pinker's advice. Put the heavy/long/important part of a sentence at the end.